# Extending moderncv social command

Tags: moderncv

I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\makeatother

\name{John}{Doe}
\extrainfo{\href{skype:jdoe}{\faSkype{} jdoe}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

which add a clickable Skype profile on the CV.

Is there a way to extend the existing social command in order to accept Skype as optional parameter, in order to write a more readable thing like this?

```
\social[skype]{jdoe}
```

Answer (score 6):

Now it is possible to do it this way:

```
\newcommand*\skypesocialsymbol{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\social[skype][skype.com/user/jdoe]{jdoe}
```

You just have to change the url accordingly.

Comment: Not-a-LaTeX-expert here. I love your one-liner solution. I had to adapt it though: `\newcommand*\skypesocialsymbol{{\faSkype~}}` worked.

Comment: @MorganCourbet's solution works well. It simply requires the `fontawesome` package.

Comment: Amazing thank you. You can also use `\newcommand*\anysocialsymbol{\includegraphics[height=11pt]{anysymbol.png}}` to include any symbol btw.

Answer (score 2):

The following code in the preamble does the trick!

```
% hlink
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hlink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{#2}{#1}}}
\makeatother

% social
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\facebooksocialsymbol}{\faFacebook~}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{\faSkype~}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{facebook}}{\collectionadd[facebook]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.facebook.com/#3}}}   {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{skype}}   {\collectionadd[skype]{socials}   {\protect\hlink[#3]{skype:#3}}}              {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```

### Step by step explanation:

Create a "hlink" command: This is needed because the skype link is not a link to a web page

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hlink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{#2}{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Create commands for the symbols that will be used. Note that the skype symbol is not in the default Font Awesome command sets and thus needs a different solution than the facebook symbol

```
\newcommand*{\facebooksocialsymbol}{\faFacebook~}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{\faSkype~}
```

Lastly, edit the original social command to include these symbols:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{facebook}}{\collectionadd[facebook]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.facebook.com/#3}}}   {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{skype}}   {\collectionadd[skype]{socials}   {\protect\hlink[#3]{skype:#3}}}              {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```